# Eclipse android project - can't import libraries

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I'm quite new to android dev.
I'm starting a project in android studio, but I'm looking at some examples of other old apps, that seem to be only running on eclipse.

When I download these old apps I always get in eclipse some kind of missing package reference within the code, in this case it is complaining that the library **com.jaalee.sdk** and other are missing.

But looking at the project the library seems there.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong, how can I solve this issue?
Does Java/eclipse have some kind of package manager distribution like in c# Nuget packages?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

hey what I am getting is that you haven't installed the com.jaalee.sdk package ,try to delete it and reinstall it once again.
let me know what happens,it works or not,else I will try to solve it once more.

also visit this link ,and see if it can be helpful:-https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/814360/